# matlab function which is a function of an intergral

Tags: function, matlab

I need to write my own function which has the form `f(x,y)=Integrate(g(x,y,z),z from 0 to inf)`. so the code I used was:

```
function y=f(x,y)
g=@(z)exp(-z.^2)./(z.^x).*(z.^2+y.^2).^(x/2);% as a function of x,y and z
y=quadgk(g,0,inf)
```

and if I call it for a single value like `f(x0,y0)`, it works but if I try to calculate something like `f([1:10],y0)`, then the error message says that there is something wrong with the times and dimension. In principle I can use for loops but then my code slows down and takes forever. Is there any help I can get from you guys? or references?

I'm trying to avoid the for loop since in matlab it's much faster to use matrix computation than to use for loop. I wonder if there is any trick that I can take advantage of this feature.

Thanks for any help in advance,

Lynn

Comment: In your case, I think you should use a for loop. If you have `x=1:10` I guess it would not take much more than ten times the time of the normal function.

Comment: well if I do for loop for 10 times that's not a problem, but I then need to pass this function to another function to do some optimization, and in order to do that this f function has to be able to accept vector input and produce vector output...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try to transpose the interval, creating row based values instead of column based `f([1:10]',y0)`. Otherwise something in your function might be wrong, for example to get `x^y` to work with lists as input, you have to prefix with a dot `x.^y`. The same for mulitply and division I think..

Comment: Thank you so much to your answer, I tried both row and column vectors,and I made sure that I put a dot after every * and ^ and /.,I should have included the exact function I wrote down.

Answer (score 0):

If loop is no problem for you, you should do something like:

```
function y2=f(x,y)
y2=zeros(size(x));

for n=1:numel(x)
  g=@(z)exp(-z.^2)./(z.^x(n)).*(z.^2+y.^2).^(x(n)/2);% as a function of x,y and z
  y2(n)=quadgk(g,0,inf)
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, and I did try the for loop, but then it takes forever to run my entire code. This function is just part of my project. After I defined this function, I will need to perform an inverse Laplace to it and then maximize the resulting function...so if I use for loops every time the code will be too slow, since for matlab, performing matrix computation is much faster than the for loop, just wish there is some trick to do it. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `quadk` itself uses vectors as argument for `g`. Then you have in `g` somethink like `z.^x`, which is the power of two vectors that is only defined if z and x have the same dimension. But this is not what you want.

I assume that you want to evaluate the function for all arguments in `x` and that the output vector has the same dimension as `x`. But this does not seem to be possible since even this simple example

```
g=@(x)[x;x.^2]
quad(g,0,1)
```

does not work:

```
Error using quad (line 79)
The integrand function must return an output vector of the same length as the
input vector.
```

A similar error shows when using `quadgk`. The documentation also says that this routine works only for scalar functions and this is not surprising since an adaptive quadrature rule would in general use different points for each function to evaluate the integral.

You have to use `quadv`instead, which can integrate vector valued functions. But this gives wrong results since your function is integrated in the interval [0,\infty).